# (ReactJS) Function not passing to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to pass props and functions from a parent to a child component in React. However, when I try to call the function in the child component, I receive the error: "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined**".

This would suggest that the function created in the parent element is not being accessed by the child component. Am I missing a step in my code that would allow me to reference a parent component function from a child component?

I am defining states as props in my parent component, for use in conditional rendering in my child component. I am also defining functions in the parent component, which I am trying to call in my child component.

Provided below is my code:

**Note:** The flow is supposed to work as follows: Click Sign Up button > Call SignUpClick function > render "SignUp" component (based on the conditional rendering logic outlined in the child component)

The same flow concept would apply if someone clicked the Sign In button.

**Parent Component**

```
  export default class Parent extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      SignUpClicked: false,
      SignInClicked: false,
    };

    this.SignUpClick = this.SignUpClick.bind(this);
    this.SignInClick = this.SignInClick.bind(this);

  }

    SignUpClick() {
      this.setState({
        SignUpClicked: true,
      });
    }

    SignInClick() {
      this.setState({
        SignInClicked: true,
      });
    }

  render () {

    return (
      <div>
           <Child />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class Child extends Component {

  render () {

  if (this.props.SignUpClicked) {
    return(
      <SignUp />
    ) } else if (this.props.SignInClicked) {
    return (
      <SignIn />
    )
  } else {
      return (
      <div>
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.SignUpClick.bind(this)}> Sign Up </Button>
         </div>
         <div>
           <Button onClick={this.SignInClick.bind(this)}>Sign In</Button>
         </div>
      </div>
          )
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass it as props...

Comment: `<Child onSignUp={() => this.signUp()}>`

Comment: and then on Child: `<Button onClick={() => this.props.onSingUp()}> Sign Up </Button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, where would the child component grab the references for those functions ? The parent needs to give the child access to those methods, and how does a parent pass data to a child, with props! In your case you are not passing any prop at all to the child, so here is how your parent render method should look like:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child
        signUpClicked={this.state.SignUpClicked}
        signInClicked={this.state.SignInClicked}
        onSignUpClick={this.onSignUpClick}
        onSignInClick={this.onSignInClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how a parent communicates with a child passing down props that are now accessible with `this.props`. At this point your Child component render method would look like this:

```
render () {
  const {
    signUpClicked,
    signInClicked,
    onSignUpClick,
    onSignInClick,
  } = this.props;

  if (signUpClicked) {
    return(<SignUp />);
  } else if (signInClicked) {
    return (<SignIn />);
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={onSignUpClick}> Sign Up </Button>
        <Button onClick={onSignInClick}>Sign In</Button>
      </div>
    )
 }
}
```

I used destructuring to help with readability. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Change the render method in parent class to pass SignUpClick and SignInClick to child.

```
return (
  <div>
       <Child SignInClick={this.SignInClick} SignUpClick={this.SignUpClick}/>
  </div>
)
```

Also, in the child class, access the methods as this.props.SignUpClick and this.props.SignInClick